# Getting property value of a class that belongs to another class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, audit

I have classes something like this:

```
  public class foo{

        public string FooProp1 {get; set;}

        public Bar Bar{get; set;}

    }

 public class Bar{

      public string BarProp1 {get; set;}

      public string BarProp2 {get; set;}

    }
```

I have some audit setup where If I Update Foo then I can get that property Name and value for all the property apart from the 'Bar'. Is there a way to get property name and value of 'BarProp1'.

```
  private void ProcessModifiedEntries(Guid transactionId) {
     foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList()) {
        Track audit = CreateAudit(entry, transactionId, "U");

        foreach (var propertyName in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames) {

              string newValue = entry.CurrentValues[propertyName]?.ToString();
              string originalValue = entry.OriginalValues[propertyName]?.ToString();                  
              SetAuditProperty(entry, propertyName, originalValue, audit, newValue);             
        }
     }
  }
```

I want to audit BarProp1 when Foo got changed.

Comment: If `BarProp1` was modified it will already be reported because the `Bar` is also `Modified`.

Comment: No Bar  not Modified. Only foo property has been modified But i want to get values of bar property as i want to Audit Bar property value for some other purpose.

Comment: Then define an interface that prescribes an (unmapped) computed property containing additional info for auditing.

Comment: I am new to C# , can you please Explain in brief. So I can create an Interface and My foo class will inherit from there and IN Audit I can check that my foo class Is ISomeInterface then I can perform some Logic. But What should I add in Interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want classes to report additional information to your auditing system. I think the best place to do that is in your `CreateAudit` method. The question is how.

You *could* have code in there that does something special for each incoming `entry`:

```cs
var foo = entry.Entity as Foo;
if (foo != null)
{
    // do something with foo.Bar
}

var boo = entry.Entity as Boo;
if (boo != null)
{
    // do something with boo.Far
}
```

etc.

Of course that isn't very pretty.

If you have multiple classes that need to report additional info to the auditor I would define an interface and tack that to each of these classes:

```cs
public interface IAuditable
{
    string AuditInfo { get; }
}

public class Foo : IAuditable
{
    public string FooProp1 { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string AuditInfo
    {
        get { return Bar?.BarProp1; }
    }
}
```

And then in `CreateAudit`:

```cs
var auditable = entry.Entity as IAuditable;
if (auditable != null)
{
    // do something with auditable.AuditInfo
}
```

And even if there's only one class that needs this behavior I would still use the interface because it makes your code self-explanatory.